# Nginx configuration for the Tornado websocket demo?

Tags: nginx, websocket, chat, tornado, demo

Can someone please provide me with Nginx configuration for the Tornado websocket chat demo? the demo is located under /tornado/demos/websocket...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A config like this will work:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    upstream chatserver {
        server 127.0.0.1:8888;
    }

    server {
        # Requires root access.
        listen       80;

        # WebSocket.
        location /chatsocket {
            proxy_pass http://chatserver;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://chatserver;
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to run Nginx as root in order to listen on port 80. Now you can visit "localhost" with your browser. [More info on Nginx and websockets here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html).