# Issue with nginx config for a Tornado WebSocket server

Tags: python, nginx, websocket, tornado

I'm hosting a Python WebSocket server written in `Tornado`. For that purpose I've written an `nginx` config, but it doesn't seem to work.
The exact issue is that when I try to establish a connection from a WS client, it fails and the following record appears in the server logs:

```
WARNING:tornado.access:400 GET / (127.0.0.1) 2.07ms
```

My application is set up so that only WebSockets will be served on root (`/`), but judging by the logs, it seems that my request somehow gets transformed to HTTP, therefore my server blocks the connection.

This is my `nginx` configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    # host name to respond to
    server_name ws.example.com;

    location / {
        # switch off logging
        access_log off;

        # redirect all HTTP traffic to localhost:8080
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # WebSocket support (nginx 1.4)
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

A config from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367215/nginx-configuration-for-the-tornado-websocket-demo) question didn't work - the issue was the same.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361894/tornado-python-tornado-server-integration-with-nginx) question looks similar, but its answer also didn't help.
Any ideas?